# Windows server 2003 Not Responding

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-sbs

I have a windows server 2003 smbs that was working a couple of days ago but now is not.
The server will not respond to pings on local network as well as request for remote desktop as well as looking at shares. I have gone through and made sure that all ports are forwarded properly in the router as well as making sure that the static ip address on the server is set correctly as well as the dns. Could anyone off some advise I am rely dispirit.

Thank you.

Comment: more information/background information is required.  It could be anything!

Answer (score 1):

Have an on-site technician try to access the server locally. If that doesn't work, then reboot. Please post more details.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not responding even to pings, chances are fair that it's down (off, locked up completely, showing a blue screen, etc.) or off the network (loose connection, bad port, etc.). About the only thing you can do remotely is see whether the switch or router port that it's plugged into shows a connection (assuming that you have equipment that allows those checks and that you know which port it's on), and even that won't let you do anything.